# JBPM process management console not loading

Tags: jbpm

I am kind of exploring JBPM...Need your help....
I have installed JBPM with the help of following URL 
http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0.1/userguide/jBPMInstaller.html

But after installation I am not able to open the JBPM process management console on browser [i.e workbench].Installation is successful and also I am not getting any error when I started the jbpm[i.e. ant start.demo]

Not able to load http://<>:8080/jbpm-console url.Port 8080 is not occupied ..check with tcpView tool...Any suggestions?Please help....:)

Comment: Have you started the app serveR?

Comment: yes application server is starting....wildfly...

Comment: Check it, it might be running on a different port.

Comment: you will need to show us the server.log file inside the logs directory, that's where the issues is probably displayed.